# How to launch android files app using Linking

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent

I'm trying to redirect users to the default files app in Android through my React Native app. On iOS I managed to get it working using the following line:

```
Linking.openURL('shareddocuments://');
```

But I can't find the scheme URL for the default files app in Android. I've tried using the package name with a Chrome Intent but that just doesn't seem to work.

```
Linking.openURL('intent:#Intent;scheme=file;package=com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity;end');
```

Has anyone know how to accomplish something like that?